# Merging selected colums from multiple text file to one text file using Python

Tags: python, merge

I have multiple text files with 4 columns (tab separated). Each file will have around 2000 rows. Using Python, how can i create a new file that looks like this?

```
file1column1 file1column4 file2column4 file3column4 ...fileNcolumn4
```

Thanks.

Here is the code i tried:

```
file_lists = ['file1.data', 'file2.data']

temp_data = []

for a_file in file_lists:
   file_h = open(a_file)
   a_list = []
   csv_reader = csv.reader(file_h, delimiter='\t')
   for row in csv_reader:
       if afile == "file1.data":
            a_list.extend([row[0], row[3]]) 
       else:
            a_list.append(row[3])
    temp_data.append((n for n in a_list))
    file_h.close()

with open('output.data', 'w') as output_file:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter='\t')
   for row in list(zip(*temp_data)):
       csv_writer.writerow(row)
output_file.close()
```

Courtesy: [Combining columns of multiple files in one file - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072082/combining-columns-of-multiple-files-in-one-file-python)

I am getting results in following format though:

```
file1column1 file2column4
file1column4 file2column4
file1column1 file2column4
file1column4 file2column4
```

Comment: You could use a `csv.reader` for each file and `zip` to run through them in parallel.

Comment: Please post the code if u have tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
file_lists = [('file1.data', 1), ('file1.data', 3), ('file2.data',3)]

temp_data = []

for a_file in file_lists:
    file_h = open(a_file[0])
    a_list = []
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_h, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
       a_list.append(row[a_file[1]])           
    temp_data.append((n for n in a_list))
    file_h.close()

with open('output.data', 'w') as output_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in list(zip(*temp_data)):
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

You don't need to close file when you use with ... as

Comment: This resulted on following format (just the single column from file 2 column 4):

file2column4\n
file2column4

Comment: @Dave: sorry I forgot some spaces... I have edited my answer.