# Combining columns of multiple files into one - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple script that would import a specific column from multiple data files (.csv like file but with no extension) and export it all to one file with filenames in each column header. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072082/combining-columns-of-multiple-files-in-one-file-python/68648302#68648302) (also the code bellow by [shaktimaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531036/shaktimaan)), which seems to do almost exactly the same, however, I got to some difficulties. Firstly I am still getting  ''expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list'' error and I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. I am not sure if the File_name variable should contain file names or file paths, and if I should use a different function to import files because my files don't have a .csv extension in the name.

Thank you for your help,

Šimon

```
import csv

# List of your files
file_names = ['file1', 'file2']

# Output list of generator objects
o_data = []

# Open files in the succession and 
# store the file_name as the first
# element followed by the elements of
# the third column.
for afile in file_names:
    file_h = open(afile)
    a_list = []
    a_list.append(afile)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_h, delimiter=' ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        a_list.append(row[2])
    # Convert the list to a generator object
    o_data.append((n for n in a_list))
    file_h.close()

# Use zip and csv writer to iterate
# through the generator objects and 
# write out to the output file
with open('output', 'w') as op_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(op_file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in list(zip(*o_data)):
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
op_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi.
Could you please give us the exact error youre getting ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I ran your code on my end and it worked fine. file1 and file2 are in your working directory?

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error.

'IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-b2584735b50a> in <module>
     17     csv_reader = csv.reader(file_h, delimiter=',')
     18     for row in csv_reader:
---> 19         a_list.append(row[6])
     20     # Convert the list to a generator object
     21     o_data.append((n for n in a_list))

IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: You can try it with my test files. Here is [link] ( https://filesender.cesnet.cz/?s=download&token=4fa806b2-5646-404b-ac87-09af570c2c1c)

Comment: That's because `row` doesn't have 7 items for you to access `row[6]`. Probably a blank line in the csv. Make sure `len(row) > 6` before trying to access it.